# How to use lme4.0 with lmerTest?

Tags: r, lme4

I am wondering if anyone has faced this issue before. I use the package `lmerTest` to run mixed-effects models in R because it has a handy way of providing p-values. This package by default loads the most current version of the `lme4` package. However, the `lme4` current version has some issues and [it sometimes doesn't converge](https://hlplab.wordpress.com/2014/03/17/old-and-new-lme4/#more-1554), so the `lme4` developers have made available a new package (named `lme4.0`), which is a bugfix-only version of the old pre-1.0 `lme4`. This works great, and the models usually converge, so that is what I use to analyze my data.

I would like to have `lmerTest` but have it load `lme4.0` instead of the current version of lme4.Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: lmerTest depends on lme4. You can't use it with lme4.0. If you observe problems with convergence you should report that to the lme4 developers. However, it may well be that the problem is with your model and data.

Comment: @Roland: Thanks for the comment. I should have clarified that the same model that doesn't converge when I use the current version of lme4, converges fine when using lme4.0.

Comment: It may converge, but have you checked if it is a well behaved model in lme4.0?

Comment: Two more questions: (1) are the convergence warnings you get equal to the fairly lengthily discussed (on r-sig-mixed-models@r-project.org) false positives in recent versions of `lme4`? (2) Do you get the same parameter estimates in `lme4.0` and `lme4` (what version of `lme4` are you using?)  If so, then you might as well use `lme4`.

Comment: @BenBolker: (1) yes, they are...That is why I didn't want to get into the details of the models here as I've read on them a lot in the r-sig-mixed list (2) yes, they re quite similar in most cases (I'm using the most updated version of lme4 on CRAN).

Comment: PS With regard to the link you give: I've asked for reproducible, problematic examples so that we can test to see whether they've been resolved by our more recent changes (most importantly changing the default optimizer), but so far haven't gotten any feedback.

Comment: In that case why not just use `lme4`?  Or install the latest (development) version of the package which suppresses the false-positive warnings?  (If you can't use `devtools::install_github` to install it directly from Github, let me know your OS and I can post a binary on `http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/repos` ..)

Comment: I think if you want to use `lmerTest` with `lme4.0`, you will have to download an older version of `lmerTest` and hack it to expect `lme4.0` rather than `lme4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really feasible without serious hacking: essentially, take an older version of `lmerTest`, download the source, hack it to look for `lme4.0` rather than `lme4`, and install locally.  Or download (from the CRAN archives) and install older versions of `lme4` and `lmerTest` (and `pbkrtest`: maintaining an archaic setup will get progressively more difficult, and you will have to backport or forego bug fixes as they appear in newer versions).

Since many of the problems with new `lme4` have been cleaned up with the switch in default optimizers from Nelder-Mead to BOBYQA, my advice would be to run a range of comparisons between `lme4.0` and `lme4`, convince yourself that there are no problems (and send information about persistent problems to the `lme4` maintainers, who would greatly appreciate it!), and move on to the new version.